# mapview stopped downloading tiles

Tags: google-maps, android-mapview, tiles, download

Strange problem:

I have a program that was happily downloading map tiles in my mapview.
suddenly....poof no more tiles.

I did not change anything that might affect the download proces. all the code stayed the same,
the downloading stopped.

I was wondering if that could have anything to do with the date change.
it seemed to happen just after midnight.

any ideas where to look?

Comment: Did you reach your usage limit for the day?

Comment: is not the usage limit 25000? i will try again in the morning, maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Very silly, but did find at least one person who made the same mistake.

While copy pasting the onstop into onresume i forgot to change super.onstop into super.onresume.